# Reading a 3gp file on Safari

Tags: iphone, safari, 3gp

first, I'm sorry if my english is not very good, I'll do my best :)

As said in title, I would like to read 3gp files in Safari, on an iPhone.

First, I have a file on my machine, and a litle test page with a link wich points on this file. When I clic on the link, it works, Safari allows to read the video.

What I really want to do is to contruct dynamically the file from a part of a mail file. 
When I use this method, Safari doesn't want to read the file. I have a black screen with an arrow reading barred.

I thought the response headers might be different, but I don't know what can be responsible for this behavior.

Headers that differ are :

`nothing                   / Cache-Control:private

nothing                   / Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="IMG_1925.3gp"

nothing  / Content-Transfer-Encoding:Binary

Content-Type:text/plain / Content-Type:application/octet-stream

ETag:W/"91103-1353574396000" / nothing

Last-Modified:Thu, 22 Nov 2012 08:53:16 GMT / rien 
nothing / Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
nothing / Pragma:No-cache`

Do you which one could provoke this behavior on Safari ? 
If you think it's not a header problem, what can it be ?

Thank a lot for your answers,
Perrine

Edit: An other problem : when I try to access the file with my litle link in text file, it works on iPhone BUT it doesn't work on android .... What can I do to have something which works on iPhone AND Android ? 
Please, help!!